# Fixing Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've experienced an issue while using minify plugin (no error otherwise), for some reason.

According to console, I run jQuery 3.6.1 and the following error is thrown:

Fixing Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
at S.fn.load

Am I correct into rewriting this code to fix onload?

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){tdAffix.compute_wrapper();tdAffix.compute_top();setTimeout(function(){tdAffix.compute_top()},

jQuery(window).on('load', function(){tdAffix.compute_wrapper();tdAffix.compute_top();setTimeout(function(){tdAffix.compute_top()},
```

What I am struggling with is indexOf

```
-1==e.indexOf(l)&&a(b).eq(l).css("-webkit-backface-visibility","");-1==e.indexOf(g)&&a(b).eq(g).css("-webkit-backface-visibility","")}}}


function(c,d){var e=c.src,f=b.st.iframe;a.each(f.patterns,function(){return-1<e.indexOf(this.index)?(this.id&&(e="string"==typeof this.id?e.substr(e.lastIndexOf(this.id)+this.id.length


{if(-1!==b.className.indexOf("wp-image")){var c=jQuery(b).parent(),d=c.attr("href");-1!==d.indexOf(document.domain)&&-1!==d.indexOf("uploads")&&c.addClass("td-modal-image")}})});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the full code?

Comment: The full code is sadly a minified version with thousands of lines